# Given a known background color (#000) and a known foreground color (#fff), how can I calculate the opacity to match reference images?

Tags: svg, colors, imagemagick

I have a short video clip that starts with a perfectly black background. Over a short period, it will transition in with a fully white caption. The in-between frames show various gray tones.

In another SO question, I found a one-liner that allows me to find the brightest pixel:

```
convert 0000$a.png -colorspace HSB -format %c histogram:info:-  | sort -t',' -gr -k 3 | head -1 | sed 's/.* hsb.*,.*,\([0-9.]*\)%.*/\1/
```

Over my range of video frames, I get a nice log curve from 0 to 100. I had figured that I could take these numbers, plop them into the svg's opacity for the text element, and export a png.

However, the results are wildly different than the original that I'm trying to imitate. Frame 50 Has a 8.49447% brightness. It looks like the following:

[image]

This looks black to my eyes (frame 49 measures at 0%).

If I set the white text to 8.49% opacity, I get the following results:

[image]

This is still pretty dark, but it's much more perceptible.

Clearly, pixel brightness isn't analogous to the opacity of white on a black background. The numbers themselves are *sort of* right, in that my curve fades in at what looks like the right rate, but it's starting brighter and staying brighter frame by frame, up until they both hit 100%.

Can I convert this value to what the matching opacity should be? Do I need a different value entirely? If this was only a few frames, I'd just eyeball them, but I have what looks like low-thousands of them to get right (for various scenes).

The command line I'm using is the following:

```
for a in `seq -f %06g 50 72`; do o=`convert $a.png -colorspace HSB -format %c histogram:info:-  | sort -t',' -gr -k 3 | head -1 | sed 's/.* hsb.*,.*,\([0-9.]*\)%.*/\1/'`; p=0`echo "scale=6;$o/100"|bc -l`; sed "s|ABC|$p|" ../svg/scene000.svg > ../temp.svg; /Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape -f /Users/user/ep1/temp.svg -e /Users/user/ep1/4k/$a.png -z > /dev/null; echo -e "$a.png\t$o\t\t$p"; done
```

And I'm seeing these values for the frames:

```
000050.png  8.49447     0.084944
000051.png  11.0702     0.110702
000052.png  16.6186     0.166186
000053.png  27.7847     0.277847
000054.png  32.5076     0.325076
000055.png  40.0663     0.400663
000056.png  46.6477     0.466477
000057.png  52.6319     0.526319
000058.png  62.2218     0.622218
000059.png  64.1088     0.641088
000060.png  71.5642     0.715642
000061.png  76.4314     0.764314
000062.png  81.3782     0.813782
000063.png  81.3782     0.813782
000064.png  85.1114     0.851114
000065.png  85.1114     0.851114
000066.png  88.8427     0.888427
000067.png  91.8013     0.918013
000068.png  93.7057     0.937057
000069.png  94.4534     0.944534
000070.png  97.7247     0.977247
000071.png  97.7247     0.977247
000072.png  99.8274     0.998274
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue due to the log scale. You could try to linearize it by taking the exp of the values and normalize to 0 to 100 again.  But how did you set the opacity? Can you show the command? Rather than setting the opacity of the text, you could just change the grayscale value of the text color. But that should produce the same results changing the opacity.

Comment: @fmw42 I'll edit in the command line. I'm just sedding in an opacity value into a style attribute (and those are 0 to 100).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing but you have to figure out if you work in perceptual (gamma-corrected) or linear light.